# Integral of $r$-form over singular $r$-simplex

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I define a singular $r$-simplex as a smooth map $f$ from the standard $r$-simplex $\Delta^r$ into a smooth manifold $M$. The integral of an $r$-form $\omega$ over an $r$-simplex is then defined as
$$ \int_{\Delta^r} f^* \omega $$
where $^*$ denotes the pull-back. My question is: for two $r$-simplexes $f_1$ and $f_2$ with the same image in $M$, is the integral of $\omega$ over them the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider the 1-form $d\theta$ on the unit circle, and the two 1-simplices
$$
f:[0, 1] \to R : x \mapsto (\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x)  \\
g:[0, 1] \to R : x \mapsto (\cos 4\pi x, \sin 4\pi x)
$$

These have the same image (the whole circle), but the integrals are $2\pi$ and $4\pi$ respectively.

As a simpler example, consider the two maps $f$ and $g$ of the unit interval defined by $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1-x$. They have the same image. What is 
$f^{*} (dt) (x) [1]$? (where $dt$ is the constant 1-form whose value on the vector $[1]$ is $1$.)

By definition, it's 
$$
dt( f_{*} (x) [1] )
$$
and since $f'$ is the constant $1$, this is 
$$
dt([1]) = 1.
$$

A similar analysis for $g$ shows that $g^*(dt)(x)[1] = -1$.

The integrals of these over the unit interval are therefore $+1$ and $-1$.